# How to arrange many divs side by side and one under the other

Tags: css

Here is what I want to do;

[Pinterest](http://pinterest.com/all/?category=photography)

Let's say I have 10 or more rectangular divs. I want to put those divs 5 of them side by side and the other 5 of them are under the others. My question is;

How should I name the divs ? Should the class name change for every div or the IDs change or Should I give;

```
float:left
```

attribute to all divs to let them align side by side. So the other five will be placed under them when there is no place horizontally.

I mean how should the structure of these 10 divs (or more) be ?

Comment: I'm not sure you understand how classes and ids work... Classes are used when you want to apply style to more than 1 element. Ids are used ONCE per page. If these divs should all be styled the same, they will all have the same classnames... The effect you are trying to use can easily be achieved with [Nested](https://github.com/suprb/Nested) as well.

Comment: If you float them the next row will begin at the end of the highest div from the previous row. You need js to make them fit exactly under the previous row block or fixed height to all div elements.

Comment: It can't be done automatically AFAIK, a script appears to position each one absolutely, then add `top` and `left` properties to position them based on others' heights.

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri I had tried just floating them left and leave the rest to browser. It works but I have some problems when floating the elements. So I think there should be a better way to implement this.

Comment: @brbcoding yes I know how classes and ID's work. :) I'll check Nested. Thanks.

Comment: @Mtok I think this is what you are looking for -> http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: if you have a look at the source of the page you will see that the divs are all absolutely positioned - I think they have made their own plugin to resize the container, add in new pictures as you scroll down and position the elements as they are added

Comment: maybe this demo can help: http://jsfiddle.net/gK2Vn/

Comment: @Morpheus please put is as an answer, in comments it's easy to miss.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may find the [Wookmark JQuery](http://www.wookmark.com/jquery-plugin) pluggin useful. Its like [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) but I think its easier. Put all your images inside a div, reference it in the `<script></script>` and it will basically give the same effect as Pininterest.

Comment: Someone suggested to add [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com) as an answer. I suggest for you to edit your answer and add link to Masonry :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use class you can use it for several objects without changing the name.
Try this:

```
<style>
.container {
    overflow:auto;
}
.sidebyside {
    float:left; 
    width:100px; 
    height:100px; 
    border-style:solid; 
    margin:5px;
}
.belowdiv {
    width:300px; 
    height:100px; 
    border-style:solid; 
    margin:5px;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="sidebyside">div0</div>
    <div class="sidebyside">div1</div>
    <div class="sidebyside">div2</div>
    <div class="sidebyside">div3</div>
    <div class="sidebyside">div4</div>
</div>
<div class="belowdiv">div5</div>
<div class="belowdiv">div6</div>
<div class="belowdiv">div7</div>
<div class="belowdiv">div8</div>
<div class="belowdiv">div9</div>
```

Comment: -1 You completely miss the point of what happens when divs with different heights are in one container.

Comment: @Layne You can put all above in another div and do the same work to arrange them horizontally and simply support different sizes.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to create a container for all of the divs. And the add the 10 divs under them.

```
<div id="divContainer">

    <div class="theDiv">
         //Div content 1
    </div>

    <div class="theDiv">
         //Div content 2
    </div>

    <div class="theDiv">
         //Div content 3
    </div>

    <div class="theDiv">
         //Div content 4
    </div>

    <div class="theDiv">
         //Div content 5
    </div>

    <div class="theDiv">
         //Div content 6
    </div>

    <div class="theDiv">
         //Div content 7
    </div>

    <div class="theDiv">
         //Div content 8
    </div>

    <div class="theDiv">
         //Div content 9
    </div>

    <div class="theDiv">
         //Div content 10
    </div>

</div>
```

And after that you add the styling.

- First, set a width to the divContainer, lets say the container is 1000px and each div inside is 200px.
- Second, you add the float property.

Something like.

```
<style>  
    #divContainer {background: blue; width: 1000px; float: left;}
    .theDiv {background: pink; float: left;}
</style>
```

And then after that you can offcourse more properties to make it look better like margins and so on.

Hope this helps you =)

Comment: This will not work as different divs with different heights will make it look really bad http://jsfiddle.net/UfVrH/